# How to form a query that will return result even if fields have different data types?

Tags: mongodb

How to form a MongoDB query that will return result even if data is in different form.

Ex: I have collection which has following structure, where "documentId" has value 16641 but sometime data type is string and some time its number.

like in SQL we can use '' in where clause to query value of different type, can I do the same in MongoDB.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just query using the `$in` operator. For example you could do this to match the two documents you have as example by the "Sr No" field.

```js
db.collection.find({"Sr No": {$in : [2, "1"]}});
```

Comment: what will you propose for documentId also I would be doing this from NodeJs and for multiple fields, the approach seems cumbersome, Is there an alternative ?

Comment: I think the above answer is an example based on your documents in your question. Instead of `Sr No`, you can use `docuemntId`. Have those documentIds in an array and pass it in